# Smart UV Project not projecting the full image

Tags: uv

When using "Smart UV Project" the UV is distributed to the left side and not evenly though the whole image, all transforms are applied.
[image]

Comment: I believe the problem is related to you not using appropriate seams on your mesh: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/208106/123064

Comment: i suggest you do some youtube tutorials on uv unwrapping and seams.

Comment: Although it's good to learn proper UV unwrapping with seams etc. to get really good UV maps, the _Smart UV Project_ is usually the method for quick unwrapping without the need for any seams at all - so don't let them tell you you're missing seams here ;) Thing is, by default this method is set to _Correct Aspect_, so it tries to preserve the size relations between all UV islands created, and these long pieces use the most space while smaller parts won't fill the rest. This method is not optimizing the space usage. You might want to enable _Scale to Bounds_, but note that it stretches the UVs.